# Stunnel Connection Issue: 140943F2 SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message

Tags: stunnel

Cant seem to connect using stunnel to the other party.
Getting an error:
SSL_connect: 140943F2: error:140943F2:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line to the stunnel config fixed the problem:

> sslVersion=SSLv3

Comment: I got similar message when I use svn client to check out my source code from svn server. Could I use the same settings? Where is the config file.

Answer (score 2):

The other party doesn't seem to speak SSL/TLS. Please ensure the remote side expects SSL on the port you're connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

i have detected, that this error occurs when my server is scanned, if to be exact pop3 on port 995.

Here is some data from my server log:

```
Jan  9 07:52:42 mail.lpic.lt dovecot: [ID 583609 mail.error] pop3-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:140943F2:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message: SSL alert number 10
Jan  9 07:52:42 mail.lpic.lt dovecot: [ID 583609 mail.info] pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 2 secs): user=<>, rip=175.184.161.239, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS: SSL_read() failed: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure: SSL alert number 10
Jan  9 07:52:43 mail.lpic.lt dovecot: [ID 583609 mail.error] pop3-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:140943F2:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message: SSL alert number 10
Jan  9 07:52:43 mail.lpic.lt dovecot: [ID 583609 mail.info] pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 3 secs): user=<>, rip=124.88.55.93, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS: SSL_read() failed: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure: SSL alert number 10
```

trying to figure out, if it always when I am scanned or when my clients connect. I do not hurry to put

```
sslVersion=SSLv3
```

or

```
sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2
```

because i have some users who use alpine or even pine to check emails... so do not ant to block client's which support only SSLv2

hope my message will be usefull to someone.